# How to assign a variable to df while iterating

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Below is the code

```
list_keys = ["model no","size","shape"]

for key in  list_keys:
    df[key]=""
for i in df.index:
    df.URL.ix[i] = "https:"+df.URL.ix[i]
    df.dictionary_quick_detail.ix[i] = json.dumps(dictionary_extractor(df.URL.ix[i])[0])
    temp_dict = json.loads(df.dictionary_quick_detail.ix[i])

    for key in list_keys:
        df.key.ix[i] = some_function(key)
```

How do I make **key** a variable? The error i got was:

> DataFrame doesn't have attribute key

Comment: It's `df[key]`.

Comment: I'm assuming this line is the error `df.key.ix[i] = some_function(key)`, change to `df[key].ix[i] = some_function(key)`

Comment: Yes, It's working fine now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to get into the habit of referencing columns in pandas using square brackets `[]`, by doing this you avoid subtle errors like this, when using dot notation pandas looks for attributes, methods and then columns in that order. It won't necessarily create a column and it can lead to ambiguous behaviour

Comment: Might as well do it in one go too: `df.ix[i, key]`

Comment: @EdChum Thanks. I will do that.